Relation between reduced norm and usual norm of central simple algebras
I have learned the notion of reduced Norms of Central Simple Algebras. I have been able to show Nrd$^n$ = $N$ where N is the usual norm i.e. determinant of left multiplication and n is the degree of the central simple algebra A only in the case $A=M_n(k)$.
Now my question is how to do it for any general central simple algebra A?

Hint. Let $L/k$ be a splitting field of $A$, and let $f:A\otimes_kL \overset{\sim}{\to} M_n(L)$ be an isomorphism of $L$-algebras.
By definition, $Nrd_A(a)=\det(f(a\otimes 1))$. Now, can you relate $\ell_a)$ and $\ell_{f(a\otimes 1)}$, as well as their determinants?

here do you mean $det (l_{f(a\otimes 1)})$?
